# fork/vfork are failing but return an out of bounds errno

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface, fork

I have a piece of software running on a 64 bit Cent 5.8 Final box, kernel 2.6.18.  This piece of software using `fork` and `vfork`.  Recently some failures occurred, and in my logging I can see that `fork` or `vfork` failed, emitting a return code of -1.  Cool, everything one would expect after a system call failure.

The interesting part is the `errno` that is logged.  Because it is `errno` 513.  I was under the impression that the highest `errno` was 131.  Does anyone know how this is possible?  Any insight into this issue would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I would contact the software author first. Clearly it's doing something wrong.

Comment: Is this the error you see after tracing the process or what gets returned back?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I first contacted an engineer at the company that makes the software.  He said to me the error was a result of an out of bounds error because the `errno` returned to the caller was 513.

Comment: @MIfe I saw the error in logging for the software that calls `fork`/`vfork`.  When it fails, it simply states the failing process (`fork`) and the `errno` (513).